# The bitcoin address space seems to be closer to 2^40, not 2^160

Tags: hash, hacking, base58, ripemd160

The Base58 Encoding of a public key hash outputs:  "A set of 58 alphanumeric symbols consisting of easily distinguished uppercase and lowercase letters (0OIl are not used)"

This set is a fixed string of 34 characters.

**That is to say, "A bit coin wallet's address is 34 characters, each character being one from a possible set of 58"**

So the total possible addresses is 58^34 which is just slightly less than 2^40.

I understand that the hash space is 2^160, but the final result is much smaller at 2^40.  What am I missing?

> Edit:  I made a simple math mistake reducing 58^34 to a power of two
>   by adding not multiplying the exponents...  The bitcoin address is
>   sufficient to contain the 2^160 possible hashes:  58^34 is 904
>   octodecillion (60 decimal digits), and 2^160 is 1 quindecillion (49
>   decimal digits)... the larger number accounts for the version byte and
>   checksum.

Comment: As mentioned, the first character is fixed and four bytes are a "checksum" so it's more like ~58^29 ~= 2^170 >> 2^160.

Answer (score 5):

No, 58^34 is greater than 2^160: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2**160+%3E+58**34](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%2a%2a160%20%3E%2058%2a%2a34)

Note, that the address also contains a checksum and a network id not carrying additional information. That's why the numbers are not equal.